# ParseCrashReporting.framework is missing

Tags: parse-platform, crash, ios-frameworks

I'm trying to add ParseCrashReporting in my app, but I can't find framework. According to the guide I had downloaded SDK (was trying both new and existing project for ObjC and Swift) but file ParseCrashReporting.framework just missed. Is it archive's error or incorrect description in guide? Where could I get latest ParseCrashReporting framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been deprecated and removed from latest sdk as announced in their newsletter. Check below issue for email message:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/247

Comment: Oh. Thank you for information. I think guys should write about it in their blog.